# How to pack two msi files and run a condition between them?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, bootstrapping, bootstrapper

I need to pack two msi files in one setup.exe file (via bootstrapper) and run only one of them depending on condition (machine is x64 or x86).
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You could pack the two msi files using iexpress.exe (a standard Window's tool) and also add a custom batch file which you set as the start command of your iexpress package. The batch script would determine the architecture and start the corresponding msi file:

```
if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% EQU x86 (
  echo "x86"
  call setup-x86.msi
) ELSE (
   echo "x64"
   call setup-x64.msi
)
```

Place that code in a batch file named installmsi.bat. Then later in the IExpress wizard enter the following installation command:

```
cmd.exe /C installmsi.bat
```

It is necessary to call `cmd.exe` explicitly here because otherwise IExpress will use the old `command.com`.

You probably also want to hide the batch window which can be done by setting the appropriate option in the IExpress wizard.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a program and embed both installers then have it check if the system is 64 bit or not. I wrote a blog post on writing a native app that does this at http://blog.foldertrack.com/?p=45